# CSS: Append Text into inputtext's value

Tags: java, css, jsf

Hi I have a minor problem.

The user want to append some silly text into a inputtext if certain condition is met.

Example

Normal Condition : the inputtext value="#{model.user}"

Abnormal condition: the inputtext should show only "#{model.user} SILLY IDIOT"
During abnormal condition the inputtext is ready only

Currently I render 2 different input text for different display, I am wondering if I could use CSS to append the "SILLY IDIOT" in the value.

I have tried value ="#{model.user} SILLY IDIOT" that will promote an error when JSF set the backing bean with the value. I need to set ReadOnly=true, hence the 2  inputtext.

I don't wish to change the code as it will increase complexity, so I prefer a simple css solution.

Comment: What are you evaluating which gives the second condition. Are you checking against some property? Also CSS is for applying style not for manipulating DOM objects. And there is nothing wrong in the requirement to call it abnormal, its perfectly okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CSS solution, but you could use the questionmark operator:

```
value="#{model.user} #{model.user.silly ? 'SILLY IDIOT' : ''}"
```

Comment: I'm going back office to try this out~ looks refreshing.